# Hibernate Exception: While migrating from mysql to oracle 11g db

Tags: mysql, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to change my application database from mysql to oracle 11g. I am using hibernate in this application but hibernate is throwing:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2231)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:312)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1722)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:175)
```

Below is my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
*<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.default_schema">wind</property> -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
        <!-- <property name="connection.autoReconnect">true</property> -->
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>-->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">25200</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>*
```

I am using one config file for database url and id password.

```
DATABASE_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/wind
DATABASE_USERNAME=appuser
DATABASE_PASSWORD=appuser
DATABASE_CONN_POOL_MIN=5
DATABASE_CONN_POOL_MAX=50
```

Mapping file:

```
 <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="com.nsn.abc.entity.UserInfo" table="user_info" >
            <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="id" />
                <generator class="assigned" />
            </id>
            <property name="username" type="string">
                <column name="username" length="30" not-null="true" unique="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="firstName" type="string">
                <column name="first_name" length="30" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="lastname" type="string">
                <column name="lastname" length="30" />
            </property>
            <property name="email" type="string">
                <column name="email" length="50" />
            </property>
            <property name="password" type="string">
                <column name="password" length="30" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="phoneNumber" type="string">
                <column name="phone_number" length="30" />
            </property>
            <property name="rights" type="string">
                <column name="rights" length="30" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="counter" type="int">
                <column name="counter" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="role" type="string">
                <column name="role" length="20" />
            </property>
            <property name="activeFlag" type="boolean">
                <column name="active_flag" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="info" type="string">
                <column name="info" length="45" />
            </property>
            <set name="massProvisioningHistories" table="mass_provisioning_history" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
                <key>
                    <column name="user_ref" not-null="true" />
                </key>
                <one-to-many class="com.nsn.abc.entity.MassProvisioningHistory" />
            </set>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

I have checked all the configuration and other details but still no progress.
Its throwing **SQL Error: 923, SQLState: 42000**. **with ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected** 
In the logs its genrating below query:
**Hibernate: select userinfo0_.id as id25_, userinfo0_.username as username25_, userinfo0_.first_name as first3_25_, userinfo0_.lastname as lastname25_, userinfo0_.email as email25_, userinfo0_.password as password25_, userinfo0_.phone_number as phone7_25_, userinfo0_.rights as rights25_, userinfo0_.counter as counter25_, userinfo0_.role as role25_, userinfo0_.active_flag as active11_25_, userinfo0_.info as info25_ from user_info userinfo0_ where userinfo0_.username=?**

Please suggest.

regards,
skr

Comment: Can you show the repository code throwing this exception?

Comment: does the sql execute for example in Squirrel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the application, we were using the SELECT 1 for checking the hibernate connection.

MySql supports "SELECT 1" but in oracle we need to mention "SELECT 1 from dual".

Now its working fine.

thanks for help.